# How to iterate each value which retrieve from DB and display them in UI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to iterate each value which retrieve from DB and display them in UI?
Below the code I am trying

Controller

```
def execution_results

    executionId1=params['executionId1']
    executionId2=params['executionId2']
     execution_results1 = ExecutionResult.where(:execution_id => executionId1).pluck(:parametersname,:actual_value)

     execution_results2 = ExecutionResult.where(:execution_id => executionId2).pluck(:parametersname,:actual_value)

    puts  execution_results1

     puts  execution_results2

 
 end
```

Now getting below response for execution_results1 and execution_results2 in Controller.

```
7.0ms) SELECT "execution_results"."parametersname", "execution_results"."actual_value" FROM "execution_results" WHERE "execution_results"."execution_id" = ?  [["execution_id", 8]]
(0.1ms)  SELECT "execution_results"."parametersname", "execution_results"."actual_value" FROM "execution_results" WHERE "execution_results"."execution_id" = ?  [["execution_id", 9]]

Device.usage   12
Device.name      A1
Device.number    12345

Device.usage   13
Device.name      A1
Device.number    12346
```

Now requirement is to compare above result and show them in Ui as below.Can anyone please help how to bring like this?

```
|S.No |Param Name   |Value|Param Name   |Value|Matched|
| 1.   Device.usage  12    Device.usage  13     No  
| 2.   Device.name   A1    Device.name   A1     Yes
```

Comment: when you query using `ExecutionResult` model it would have returned array of `Devices` which you can loop and create table in your html view

Comment: ok Thanks.How I have to do comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming execution_results1 and execution_results2 have the same number of records,

You can show the results in above-mentioned format by following lines in view

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.no</th>
    <th>Param Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Param Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Matched</th>
  </tr>
  <% @execution_results.each do |result, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
      <td><%= result.name %></td>
      <td><%= result.value %></td>
      <td><%= @execution_results2[index].name %></td>
      <td><%= @execution_results2[index].value %></td>
      <td><%= compare_function(result, @execution_results2[index]) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

compare_function here is a helper function which will be in your controller's helper and will look something like below

```
(execution_results1.usage == execution_results2.usage) && (execution_results1.number == execution_results2.number)
OR
Whatever condition you want to compare
```

Don't forget to change

```
execution_results1, execution_results
```

to

```
@execution_results1, @execution_results2.to_a
```

in your controller

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Please help on this below query:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119095/not-able-to-render-page-from-controller-to-view-in-rails