# Not able to render page from Controller to view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting 404 This  page is missing. I need to pass controller results to view.I have added respective controller and views.I am getting values in controller but not passing those values to views.I didn't get any errors as well.Can anyone help on this?

Below the code I am trying

Controller

```
class CompareResultsController < ApplicationController

    def compare_results

        executionId1=params['executionId1']
        executionId2=params['executionId2']
         @execution_results1 = ExecutionResult.where(:execution_id => executionId1).pluck(:parametersname,:actual_value)
    
         @execution_results2 = ExecutionResult.where(:execution_id => executionId2).pluck(:parametersname,:actual_value)
    
         puts @execution_results1
    
         puts @execution_results2
    
   
     end

     
    end
```

JS Code

```
function compareExecutionResults() {
    
        var checkBoxValue=[]
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
            checkBoxValue.push($(this).val());
        });
        var executionId1=checkBoxValue[0];
        var executionId2=checkBoxValue[1];
        
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/compare_results/compare_results",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                executionId1: executionId1,
                executionId2: executionId2
                 }),
               success: function (result) {
              if (result === 'false') {
                  alert('Description  not Updated  !!!');
                  return false;
               } else {
                  alert('Comparing Values !!!');
                  window.location.href = "/compare_results/compare_results";

                }
              }
           }); 
         }
```

routes

```
  post "/compare_results/compare_results", to: "compare_results#compare_results"
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.no</th>
    <th>Param Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Param Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Matched</th>
  </tr>
  <% @execution_results.each do |result, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
      <td><%= result.name %></td>
      <td><%= result.value %></td>
      <td><%= @execution_results2[index].name %></td>
      <td><%= @execution_results2[index].value %></td>
      <td><%= compare_function(result, @execution_results2[index]) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Html View

```
Views--compare_results--compare_results.html.erb file
```

Comment: please share project structure and routes

Comment: Actually I have created compare result button in execution_result page where executions results are showing.I am selecting checkboxes from table that needs to be compared.When i click compare result button it is fetching values from db based on id which I am getting  value from selected check boxes.But problem is same it stays at same page.It has to navigate to compare result page and show the results. But I am getting 500 internal server error.execution_result page and compare_result pages are in different folders.Is this the problem Chandan?

Comment: please check development logs for what is the root cause if still there is problem share error logs in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `compare_results` method of the controller is exposed in the `config/routes.rb` file as it is not a standard resource.

Sth like this might help:

```
post '/compare_results/compare_results', to: 'compare_results#compare_results'
```

Comment: thanks.I have added like above.I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Actually I have created compare result button in execution_result page where executions results are showing.I am selecting checkboxes from table that needs to be compared.When i click compare result button it is fetching values from db based on id which I am getting value from selected check boxes.But problem is same it stays at same page.It has to navigate to compare result page and show the results. But I am getting 500 internal server error.execution_result page and compare_result pages are in different folders.Is this the problem eikes?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not giving correct path, to check if this is the problem run the following command in terminal, if your rails version is greater than 5 then `rails routes`, or if its less than 5 then `rake routes`.

By doing this you will be able to see what URL are being served by your app. Now check if there is a URL(path) matching with the controller action. After that make sure that you have used correct path.

Note:
By path I mean which you may have given in link_to to visit this page.

Comment: Thanks.My rake routes showing this-"                              compare_results_compare_results POST     /compare_results/compare_results(.:format)                    compare_results#compare_results

Comment: Great, now make sure your the path you have given to link_to looks like this - 'compare_results_compare_results_path'

Also, you want to show the results right?, If yes then why are you setting method for route as POST?
May be you should set it as GET.

If thats not the problem, please share error logs and also the link where you are adding this path

Comment: I tired with Get it is not working.Post only getting data from data base.Where I need to use link_to?

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template errors/not_found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:css], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

Comment: okay, so link_to is basically rails ActionView helper which is similar to anchor tag of html. So I think you must have used a tag.

As per the above error rails is not able to find view template for action compare_results, make sure your view file name is 'compare_results.html.erb' OR else you can specify the template as `render 'your_file_name'` in you action.